# Facebook share and like are grabbing the title from the home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Share and like are working perfectly on my other PHP site, but on my new Rails site, it is just posting the home page url and the title from the home page.  It's also not grabbing any images when posting through FB share.

I tried everything - setting the og:title meta property, changing the href in the url param for share.php to facebook, etc.

What am I missing?  Has anyone encountered this problem on RoR?

Thanks,
Bella

Comment: have you find the answer i am facing the same problem 
<a href='http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()); ?>/&title=<?php urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>&price=<?php urlencode(poptribe_item_price($post)); ?>&quote=The pricing is $0.00 in exchange for social media post' target='_blank'><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
it is not showing title on facebook I also have added metas in header

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why. The page can't be views without a login. FB can't therefore see the page and is redirected to the log in page.